# Asp.Net multiple submit buttons, enter submits only the first

Tags: asp.net, forms, form-submit

I have a few submit buttons in my ASP.NET page. Everything works fine, but when a user hits enter button always the first submit button works. I want to fire each submit button with corresponding fields but cannot have multiple forms. Is it possible to group them without using forms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need forms, just wrap the related controls in their own panels and use the [`Panel.DefaultButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) property.

> Use the `DefaultButton` property to indicate which button gets clicked
>   **when the Panel control has focus and the user presses the ENTER key**.
>   The `DefaultButton` can be set to the identifier for a `Button` control or
>   any control that implements the `IButtonControl` interface except a
>   `LinkButton` control.

Answer (score 5):

Please use `DefaultButton` property like this

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="bt1">

<asp:TextBox runat="server" />
<asp:Button id="bt1" Text="Default" runat="server" />

</asp:Panel>
```

Please refer here :- [ASP.NET DefaultButton Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx)